# Steam with Wine having bug with popups

Tags: arch-linux, wine

I'm on Arch Linux 64 bits running Steam on a 32 bits Wine and whenever Steam opens a popup, it starts gliding towards the lower right corner, only stopping when I hover it with my mouse and disappearing when I take my mouse off of it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IJBn5pP-AA

It keeps saying

```
fixme:appbar:SHAppBarMessage unknown msg: 4
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETSTATE): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=3): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=1): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=0): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=2): stub
fixme:appbar:SHAppBarMessage unknown msg: 4
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETSTATE): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=3): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=1): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=0): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=2): stub
```

when the popup is gliding.

Also, it doesn't show it but when I'm in another "tab" of the window manager, popups still open at the same positions on the screen, even though I can't see the steam interface anymore.

Comment: Have you tried CrossOver ? Which said to have support of Steam engine

Comment: Not yet. I've tried Steam on Wine with the normal installer, Steam installed with winetricks and Steam installed with PlayOnLinux. All of which kind of work since I can open Steam but have that strange behavior.
Also, I didn't get any game to work yet but apparently, that's because I only have the 64 bits driver installed and I need the 32 bits one.

Comment: Do you absolutely, positively, no-way-around-it need to be running Steam on Wine?  If not, then you should probably run Steam natively.  Start by checking out the [Steam for Linux hub](http://steamcommunity.com/linux).

Answer (score 1):

Try PlayonLinux, winetricks or one of the other wine gui frontend/install helpers. There's a native Linux version There's no reason to install it tho.

Hopefully someday the Linux version will either have wine inter-operability or there will be Linux games.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different (non-tiling) window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Steam is already ported to Arch... have you checked AUR?

I guess you could use Wine for some of the PC-only games, but the client runs natively now